# is it possible to write git hook to check git commiter to be equal to gitolite user

Tags: git, gitolite

I realize that this breaks the core idea of DVCS, and so on, but still, is it possible to  write git hook to check if git committer is the same as gitolite user (the one specified in authorized_keys)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gitolite V3, you don't even have to write a hook, you can write a [VREF](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html), and do all kind of checks on the commits pushed.

That would be similar to the "checking author email" section:

> Some people want to ensure that "you can only push your own commits".
>
> If you force it on everyone, this is a very silly idea (see "Philosophical Notes" section of [`src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK)).
>
> But there may be value in enforcing it just for the junior developers.
>
> The neat thing is that the existing `contrib/update.email-check` was just copied to [`src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK) and it works, because VREFs get the same first 3 arguments and those are all that it cares about.
> (Note: you have to change one subroutine in that script if you want to use it)